# SSIS run batch process from differnet server

Tags: ssis

I have my SSIS package in server A and I want run a batach process in Server B,

Can this be possible in SSIS?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try running PSExec from [sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) in an execute process task

Answer (score 0):

you can use PSExec like SPE109 says, just be sure to set the -accepteula when calling it or it will just hang

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582%28VS.85%29.aspx) and the [Win32_Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) class from a [Script Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141752.aspx). The WMI classes are located in the System.Management.dll assembly. There are many examples of doing this on the internet. Here are a couple:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Remote_Process_using_WMI_.aspx

http://businessintelligencechronicles.blogspot.com/2009/05/ssis-script-task-to-monitor-if-remote.html